# You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled. In Magento 2 Admin panel Token

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, token

I am getting this error

> "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily
>   disabled"

during generating admin token in magento 2.1.12.

But admin panel is login with same username and password.

I don't know what is issue.Please Help.

Comment: please give the request body

Comment: {"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."}

Comment: reply asap.....

Comment: You gave response but I ask for json request body.

Comment: {"username":"admin","password":"admin@123"}

Comment: this is url "http://192.168.11.30/magento/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"

Comment: Admin panel is login successfully with same username and password.

Comment: looks fine. r u trying from postman or any other else?

Comment: I am Using RestClient extension with Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I am also checked in Postman.

Comment: What is your URL type ? Because it must be POST to generate token

Answer (score 1):

**Get Admin Token**

> Please check your URL action [It must be **POST**]

```
magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?admin&password=admin123
```

it will generate admin token.

> The above case i explained is working fine for webAPI in magento2
>   which i tested in **POSTMAN**.

Answer (score 0):

i also stucked in the same situation once..

then i run setup upgrade, cache clear command, that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem:

- Right username and password
- Right api endpoint
- User not locked.

The solution for that was delete the content of the table `oauth_token_request_log`.

`DELETE FROM oauth_token_request_log;`